# How to convert .vti file in other formats

Tags: 3d, vtk, imagemagick-convert, paraview, image-conversion

I have several .vti files with 3D images of rock samples. How can I convert .vti files into .vol or .raw or at least in stack of 2D images? I've tried ParaView, but didn't find any option to convert in one of above mentioned formats.

Comment: A programmatic approach is described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258810/convert-vti-files-to-open-it-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ParaView, you can save as a .tiff, which is an image stack.

Comment: but when I'm trying to save them as tiff, I'm getting the following errors:
ERROR: In C:\bbd\ecd3383f\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\IO\Image\vtkTIFFWriter.cxx, line 135
vtkTIFFWriter (00000231D23A46F0): Unsupported data type: double

ERROR: In C:\bbd\ecd3383f\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\IO\Image\vtkTIFFWriter.cxx, line 246
vtkTIFFWriter (00000231D23A46F0): Could not get data from input.

ERROR: In C:\bbd\ecd3383f\build\superbuild\paraview\src\VTK\IO\Image\vtkTIFFWriter.cxx, line 408
vtkTIFFWriter (00000231D23A46F0): Problem writing trailer.

Comment: As this is an image format, it supports only char or unsigned char.